# Why this Zero In This Line of Code

Tags: php, mysql

I have found a reference in the tutorials that this 0 returns the first row but I "Don't Get It" What if there's more than 1 row such as in the function below??
(ie: I have a table of 200 users and this column "UsersName" is just one among 10 others so why the Zero?)

Could someone please spell out why this 0 is in this line of code??

Thanks

```
function member_count() {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`UsersName`) FROM `users` WHERE `Active` = 1"), 0);
}
```

Comment: read this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_result.asp or http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you have looked up the PHP documentation? It's rather good...

```
string mysql_result ( resource $result , int $row [, mixed $field = 0 ] )
```

> row
>
> The row number from the result that's being retrieved. Row numbers
>   start at 0.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Imagine you done a `SELECT * FROM users`, where the table contains

```
name  | age
David | 29
John  | 18
Paul  | 26
```

Row 0 would be "David - 29", row 1 would be "John - 18", so forth.

Comment: Hi @Rawkode, I'm still at a loss... "The row number from the result that's being retrieved" just doesn't "Click" with me

Comment: Do you mean this 0 just means start at the top of a column?

Comment: You're telling it you want the first row, which is row zero. Alternatively you could have requested row 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: if this 0 were a 5 does that  mean that the query would just skip the first 4 entries and start reading from there?

Comment: In response to: "You're telling it you want the first row, which is row zero" is where I get confused

Comment: What if I want more results than the first (ie 0)??

Comment: @StuartKaufman - In your query, there will only be one row returned: the count of active users. Additionally, many programming languages are 'zero-indexed', which means that the index of the first element is 0 instead of 1. The second row would be index 1 (not 2), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

look this page

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

```
mysql_result ( resource $result , int $row [, mixed $field = 0 ] )
```

Retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set.

When working on large result sets, you should consider using one of the functions that fetch an entire row (specified below). As these functions return the contents of multiple cells in one function call, they're MUCH quicker than mysql_result(). Also, note that specifying a numeric offset for the field argument is much quicker than specifying a fieldname or tablename.fieldname argument.

result

```
The result resource that is being evaluated. This result comes from a call to `mysql_query().`
```

row

```
The row number from the result that's being retrieved. Row numbers start at 0.
```

field

```
The name or offset of the field being retrieved.

It can be the field's offset, the field's name, or the field's table dot field name (tablename.fieldname). If the column name has been aliased ('select foo as bar from...'), use the alias instead of the column name. If undefined, the first field is retrieved.
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm gonna be looking over all of this and I appreciate all of you helping

Answer (score 0):

Right, it returns the first row. The query you've posted also returns one row. Read about the function COUNT() in MySQL.

You also can use that for several reasons, i.e. if the first row is also the admin user in users table and you only need it, no matter what's the autoincrement ID or username/password, etc.